# How to require environmental variables for specific build types?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to configure my build types in a way such that:

- `release` must have access to the secret key environmental variable (and should fail otherwise)
- `debug` builds do not require a secret key

The issue is that the `debug` build is failing (missing environmental variable). Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening even though `getSecretKey()` is only called from the `release` build type?

```
    buildTypes {
        def getSecretKeyOrAbort = {
            def key = System.getenv("MY_SECRET_KEY")
            if (key) return key
            else throw new GradleException("Environmental variable MY_SECRET_KEY required.")
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LICENSE_KEY', ''
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LICENSE_KEY', getSecretKeyOrAbort()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you build and run when select the Debug build type? The BuildConfig file is generated at build time, sometimes is needed to execute 2 times to access the custom constants

Comment: I do not know your method syntax (I use a different one, but there are many) however you define a method called `getSecretKeyOrAbort` and not `getSecretKey`.

Comment: `build.gradle` builds a data model for how to do builds, for all build types/product flavors. That data model is then used by tools, whether that's just the command-line `gradle`, Android Studio, or anything else. Hence, when the script is run, it will call `getSecretKey()`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to set the environment variable in all environments.

If it's in development, set **env = "dev"** for prod **env = "prod"**

And then add a key value pair in the properties file, something like this..

dev = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"

prod = "NO_KEY"

And then read these key values by taking reading the environment variable and then get it from properties file.